# change for content in java depending on boolean

Tags: java, for-loop, boolean

I want to browse a table from `0` to `NB_MAX` or from `NB_MAX` to `0` depending on a random boolean.

I tried to use the `?:` operator :

```
for (int i = (bool) ? 0 : NB_MAX; i < ((bool) ? NB_MAX: 0); i++) {
```

The problem is to switch between `i++` and `i--`.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
for (int i = (bool) ? 0 : NB_MAX; (bool) ? i < NB_MAX : i > 0; i = (bool) ? i+1 : i-1) { }
```

Comment: Hmm, saying that the last bool is always true, I don't get why ?

Comment: I double-checked it. There is invalid condition in second for expression. I have edited my answer. Should work fine now.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You're saving me a lot of time

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not very readable if you insert ternary operators inside a for loop declaration as you're attempting.

It would be far more readable to produce *two* for loops, one of which is entered depending on the condition.

```
if (bool)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NB_MAX; i++)
    {
        body(i);
    }
}
else
{
    for (int i = NB_MAX - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        body(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I will do it for 3 for, so it wouldn't be a lot readable either

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  You have 3 for loops? I see only 1 in your question.

Comment: It's the same problem, so I didn't wrote 3 times the same thing